# Change a cell value in range determined by corresponding cell

Tags: vba, excel, loops

Problem I have is that I need to print documents that is changing daily.
Database have 4 columns and data on the sheet that is changing takes value from one column and insert it into desired cell and print 4 copies as required for different departments.

Issue is that I do not want to print 500 copies straight away as it currently happens. Database have column that divide document on blocks and it is usually about 15 up to 20 of them.

I need input box for the desired block to be printed at a time. Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub SEAL()
Dim fnd As String, FirstFound As String
Dim FoundCell As Range, rng As Range
Dim myRange As Range, LastCell As Range
  fnd = InputBox("Please input Block number to print")
Set myRange = Worksheets("DATA").Range("K10:K300")
Set LastCell = myRange.Cells(myRange.Cells.Count)
Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(what:=fnd, after:=LastCell)
  If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
  Else
    GoTo NothingFound
  End If
Set rng = FoundCell
  Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
      Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)
      Set rng = Union(rng, FoundCell)
      If FoundCell.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do
        Loop
  For Each C1 In rng.Offset(0, -1)
        Worksheets("MASTER 8.1").Range("B17") = C1.Value
    For Each T1 In Worksheets("Data").Range("E1:E4")
    Worksheets("MASTER 8.1").Range("A19") = T1.Value
        Worksheets("MASTER 8.1").PrintOut
    Next
    Next
 Exit Sub
NothingFound:
  MsgBox "Block wasn't found!"
End Sub
```

Currently only problem is when i input block 1 i get blocks: 1,10,11,12 and so on printed out and i need to get exact match. Any tips?

Comment: `Set rng = Range("G10:G300").Find(Block)` is wrong, `Block` needs to be some kind of value, `String`, `Int` or similar, not a `Range` as you defined it (`Dim Block As Range`).

Comment: you may update your post with a scenario of your data and what a block is in there

Comment: My mistake i did change it to Long instead of range.

Comment: Block is only a value in whole column are numbers from 1 to 20 depend on day.